# Entering string data in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am new in Grails application development(Springsource eclipse). I used scaffolding to do the CRUD operation and got a bizarre error. Although I filled out all fields to create table I got the message that  "Property [name] of class [class racetrack.Race] cannot be null". Whenever I changed the constraint to nullable it works but put that field empty. It seems it does not accept my input.

Thanks for your help,
Reza

Comment: Please show the relevant pieces of your code: domain class, controller and maybe view if any.

Comment: Yeah. We need more information than that... but check if your form fields (in your .gsp) has the input name matching your object's attribute. I know you used scaffold but, maybe you changed the name after? If it's not that, edit this post with some code from your view and model.

Comment: Thanks Tiago! you are right. It seems that I unexpectedly changed that field name. Now it's working!

Comment: @Tiago you should make that an answer so that Reza can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your form fields (in your .gsp) has the input name matching your object's attribute. I know you used scaffold but, maybe you changed the name after? If it's not that, edit this post with some code from your view and model.